# Need code for copying a pivot table/pivot chart onto a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a data sheet. On this data sheet there is a button that creates a new data sheet and a Pivot Table using the data on the DataSheet. This button also creates another button within the new PivotTable sheet called "Create PivotChart" (which creates a Pivot Chart using the PivotTable data and puts it on a new sheet). This works perfectly fine for making one Pivot Table and one Pivot Chart, but I need to be able to create multiple Pivot Tables/Charts with the same data but different filters and such.

[image]

```
Private Sub PivotTableButton1_Click()


'Macro By ExcelChamps

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("DataTable")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="ParetoPivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="ParetoPivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ParetoPivotTable").PivotFields("Pareto")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Column Fields


'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ParetoPivotTable").PivotFields("Pareto")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlCount
.Name = "Pareto"
End With

'Insert Filter
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ParetoPivotTable").PivotFields("model_code")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With



'Format Pivot Table

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ParetoPivotTable").PivotFields("Pareto").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Count of Pareto"


    Dim objObject As Object
    Dim strCode As String
        Set objObject = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(611.25, 63, 138, 39)
        objObject.Name = "PivotChartButton"
        objObject.Caption = "Create PivotChart"
        objObject.OnAction = "PivotChartButton_Click"


End Sub

Sub PivotChartButton_Click()

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotChart").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotChart"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    Dim wksPivot As Worksheet
    Dim wksDest As Worksheet
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Dim oPT As PivotTable
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wksPivot = Worksheets("PivotTable") 'change the sheet name accordingly
    Set wksDest = Worksheets("PivotChart") 'change the sheet name accordingly

    Set oPT = wksPivot.PivotTables("ParetoPivotTable")

    Set rDest = wksDest.Range("E2:X35")

    With rDest
        Set oChart = wksDest.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height).Chart
    End With

    With oChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SetSourceData oPT.TableRange1
    End With

    wksDest.Activate

End Sub
```

Just making a copy of the Pivot Table sheet works but the button that is on the copied sheet overwrites the button that is on the original sheet...

Comment: Have you tried using a `Slicer` for this?

Comment: @Zac this works for separating the different tables but the button that creates the PivotChart based on the table still only creates the one Chart for whatever the Table is set to. I just need the button to create a new sheet with a new Chart every time the button is clicked, as opposed to overwriting the same Chart/Sheet